# expected value of $N=\min \{n\in \mathbb N:X_1 +\cdots+X_n\ge1\}$

Tags: probability, random-variables

suppose that for every $i\in \mathbb N$ \begin{equation*}X_i\sim \textrm{Pois }(1)\end{equation*}and \begin{equation*}N=\min \{n\in \mathbb N:X_1 +\cdots+X_n\ge1\}\end{equation*}what is the expected value $EN$?
I know that $X_1+\cdots+X_n\sim\textrm{Pois}(n)$ and I tried using the following equality \begin{equation*}EN=E(E(N\mid X_1+\cdots+X_k)\end{equation*} but the fact that there are so many ways to choose $X_1+\cdots+X_k$ makes me doubt how beneficial it would be. any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\Pr(N=n) = \Pr(X_1=\cdots=X_{n-1}=0\ \&\ X_n\ne 0) = \big(\Pr(X_1=0)\big)^n(1-\Pr(X_1=0)).
$$
In fact $N$ has an geometric distribution: $N$ is the number of trials need to get one success, with probability $p=1-\Pr(X_1=0)$ of success on each trial.  Its expected value is therefore $1/p$.

Comment: Technically the term is *geometric* distribution, which is the discrete counterpart of the exponential distribution. Still, +1.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that the support of each $X_i$ is a non negative integer, that makes it much clearer.

Comment: @Ian : Sorry, that was a typo.  I meant geometric, or if you like, "discrete exponential".

Answer (score 2):

Hint: note that $N = n\Leftrightarrow X_n\geq 1 \land X_1 = X_2 = \cdots = X_{n - 1} = 0$.